# MATLAB error in "ModularRobot/VR Sink": Initialization can not be evaluated

Tags: matlab, model, initialization, simulink

When i try to start a simulation that has been successfully executed before. I get two errors. Fist of them is a Model error. Second is the title. Here are the details:

[image]

Since i'm pretty much beginner in MATLAB, i tried to do some research in order to solve the problem, but the instructions wasn't simple enough to understand. What i really want to do is, execute the simulation, see how it works, and imitate the running function.

Sorry if the question is to lame to ask, but like i said, i had to start somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marty, it's nice to see you still struggling to learn some cs stuff.

Now, listen to me carefully. That's not a real bug or something that happened because of your wrongdoings.

That's just one of the few things that happens when you use outdated software. Let me guess, u used MATLAB 9, right? Well, i guess this was your problem. Try version 10 instead.

We'll meet again.